# How can I scp a file across two servers in one line?

Tags: bash, ssh, proxy, scp

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 and bash shell.  In our environment, we have to go through a proxy (a CentOS machine) to SSH properly into a destination machine (another CentOS machine).  What I would like to do is create a shortcut so that I can scp files quickly to the destination server, something like

```
scp localfile.txt davea@server:/home/davea
```

But right now, I have to do multiple commands to transfer the file …

```
scp localfile.txt davea@proxy:/home/davea
ssh davea@proxy
scp localfile.txt davea@server:/home/davea
```

Is it possible to condense the above into one line?

Answer (score 1):

How about a function in you `.bash_profile`

```
scps () {
    if [ -f $1 ] ; then
        scp $1 davea@proxy:/home/davea && ssh davea@proxy && scp $1 davea@server:/home/davea
    else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file!"
    fi
}
```

Then you can use `scps filename` to copy `filename` to `davea@server:/home/davea`.

Comment: Hi, I gave this a go but the result is that I end up SSH'ed into the proxy server and the file hasn't been transferred to the destination.

Comment: I bet, when he said `ssh davea@proxy` (and then) `scp localfile.txt davea@server:/home/davea`, Dave meant `ssh davea@proxy` and then `scp localfile.txt davea@server:/home/davea` _from the shell prompt on the `proxy` host_. Your `ssh davea@proxy && scp $1 davea@server:/home/davea` isn't going to do that. Something like `echo "scp $1 davea@server:/home/davea" | ssh davea@proxy` _might_ work, but I doubt that it's optimal.

Comment: Hi G-Man, What you say is definitely what I intended.  However, in your suggested solution, where is the "scp $1 davea@proxy:/home/davea" portion of the command?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to automatically copy files from the proxy to the destination:

```
rsync local-file user@remote-host:remote-file
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to do everything in one line.  As I udnersatnd it, your command only works once I am on the proxy server.

Comment: I would set the rsync to copy automatically, e.g. by adding to _/etc/crontab_ * * * * *  <user> bash <rsync-cmd>